# carrierwave: multiple version strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I want to create multiple versions like :large, :medium, :small. No Problem so far. But how are these methods invoked?

A simple test:

```
version :large do
  process :resize_to_fit => [1024, 1024]
end
version :large2, :from_version=>:large do
  process :resize_to_fit => [1024, 1024]
end
```

results into two different sized files. I would assume the versions to be identic. So I guess :large2  is re-reading the file (large) from disk into RMagick?

How can I do it "right"? (I would use the same RMagick-Object to create the versions) I want to try to keep on the carriewave-way and not to do too much by myself.

Thanks and regards for any hint, Phil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An example to create 3 typical image file sizes with Carrierwave using MiniMagick in the uploader.rb file

```
# Create different versions of your uploaded files. 
  version :full do
     process :resize_to_fill => [1024, 1024] 
  end

  version :large_thumb, :from_version => :full do
     process :resize_to_fill => [300, 300] 
  end

  version :thumb, :from_version => :large_thumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [100, 100] 
  end
```

## MiniMagick efficiency considerations when creating different sized images

**MiniMagick docs suggest for processing efficiency to start with the largest resolution size and work down, cascading the re-sized files instead of starting with the large one each time as a base file converted** (https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave).

> Create versions from existing versions
>
> For performance reasons, it is often useful to create versions from
>   existing ones instead of using the original file. If your uploader
>   generates several versions where the next is smaller than the last, it
>   will take less time to generate from a smaller, already processed
>   image.

You do this with the **:from_version** directive shown in the example above.

## MiniMagick resize_to_fill versus resize_to_fit, aspect ratios, scaling

MiniMagick gives you various image manipulation options. I find resize_to_fill works for my purposes better than resize_to_fit, but your mileage may vary. There are considerations when choosing an image re-sizing option, *especially in the case where the aspect ration of the original image does not match that of the resize target image*.

Here's the ImageMagick spec with all of the image magic that MiniMagick uses: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize

MiniMagick gemspec
https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But my question was about re-using the same Magick::Image object (instead of re-reading the file from disk) for further performance improvement. Also it seems to me not conducive to a better quality of the image, when it is jpeg-compressed and decompressed more often than necessary.

Comment: It's not jpeg-compressed and decompressed more times than necessary. This is how ImageMagick suggests you create different sizes. If you don't want to do it that's okay; it's your choice, but the answer is correct.  If you have a moment, read ImageMagick spec I pointed to, you can read all about how IM deals with re-sampling issues. Good luck.

Comment: My problem is not about how imagemagick is dealing with specific image-stuff. My Problem is how carrierwave does implement the instantiation for different "versions". So the question is: Is the file read from disk, for every "version" or is the ImageMagick/MiniMagick-Object re-used between them. (large and large2 in my example) And as far as i see, it does NOT read again from disk. So my assumption was just wrong and the question irrelevant. I tried with hundreds of "versions" (each the same processor) and the version-files seems to be written alltogether at the the end.